# Quick Question: If $\varphi$ is a linear map and inner product $\langle \varphi x, y\rangle = 0$, why is $\varphi \equiv 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The title says it all. If $\varphi$ is a linear map, and we have that the inner product is $\langle \varphi x, y\rangle = 0$ for all $x,y$ in the domain of $\varphi$, how does this imply that $\varphi$ is the zero map? In particular, I was told that this equation implies that $\varphi \equiv 0$ by setting $y = \varphi x$, but how does this give us the desired conclusion? I'm missing something trivial. Thank you!

Comment: The only element $z$ such that $\langle z,z \rangle= 0$ is $z=0$. So if $\varphi x$ was not $0$ for some $x$ we could take $y=\varphi x$ and get $\langle \varphi(x), \varphi(x) \rangle \neq 0$ contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$ we get $\langle \phi x, \phi x \rangle = 0$ taking $y = \phi x$ in the condition. The positive definiteness of the inner product implies $\phi x = 0$ and so $\phi \equiv 0$ as $x$ was arbitary.